# Does Bigtable send data over the network to Dataproc to perform the map stage?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm using a Google Dataproc cluster to run Spark M/R jobs against Bigtable.
Is the data sent from Bigtable to the Dataproc cluster over the network to perform the map stage or the map stage runs physically on the Bigtable cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All computation will run on Dataproc and any data needed to do that computation will need to be transferred to Dataproc over the network to make that work.

The one caveat to that is if you set filters on your scan then the Bigtable service will perform that filtering before sending data back to your job running on Dataproc.

Comment: Does that mean that it will be better to use HFS provided by worker nodes of the Dataproc cluster instead of Bigtable for storing big amount of data? I perform Spark jobs that just scan the recent data and don't need to request arbitrary rows by rowkeys.

Comment: That's a bit of a hairy design question and depends a lot on other factors. If you have data that is only being used for bulk data analysis, you might consider storing your data in Cloud Storage and using Dataproc or Dataflow for processing it. This would allow you to shut down compute resources when they aren't needed. If you store data in HDFS, your cluster must be always-on.